# PublishPost method example for Actionscript API Facebook connect required

Tags: api, actionscript, facebook

I established an extended permission with Facebook connect, works like a charm,
but i just can't seem to publish messages on my wall.

i keep getting this error:
error code 100: Invalid parameter

my code:

```
var message:String = "test facebookconnect";
var publishpost:PublishPost = new PublishPost(message, null, null, null);

publishpost.addEventListener(FacebookEvent.COMPLETE, function(e:FacebookEvent) {
    MonsterDebugger.trace(this, e);
});

publishpost.addEventListener(FacebookEvent.ERROR, function(e:FacebookEvent) {
    MonsterDebugger.trace(this, e);
});

publishpost.addEventListener(FacebookEvent.CONNECT, function(e:FacebookEvent) {
    MonsterDebugger.trace(this, e);
});


fldFacebook.post(publishpost);
```

Any clear examples/tutorials would help a lot in how to use this publishpost with the actionscript API

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

found my solution
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=46